# The Dream of Yusuf

Tags: arabic, surat-yusuf

(I am not sure if this type of questions are allowed or encouraged, because it is mainly a language-related question. If not, please tell me and I delete.)

[image]

I am trying understand the second part of what Yusuf said. I am NOT asking whether Yusuf meant they were actually prostrating or not, or related discussions. To better express myself, let me give some examples in English:

1. I saw they JUMPED.
2. I saw them JUMPING.
3. I saw them as JUMPERS.

(1) is like you are describing a moment. (2) is like you describing a duration. (3) is like you are describing a job, routine, or whatever.

My questions are: as to the second part of what Yusuf said (I saw them prostrating to me) and with the examples above in mind: in how many ways could Yusuf have said what he has said, and what would they mean?

Comment: It can only mean (1), describing a moment.